# Need to replace outdated router

Tags: router

My current router is over 5 years old and need an upgrade to reach one upstairs bedroom (that currently receives a weak signal) and support four active mobile users (4 iPhones + 3 iPads).  Does anyone have any recommendations on a cost-effective router (plus any other devices to improve download time)?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here and this question will likely be put on hold. If you can reword it to ask a better question whose answer will be useful over time, that would help. For example, ask about how to pick a good router or about which factors are important.

Answer (score 2):

Without giving product recommendations (as per @David Schwartz comment which I agree with), you should look at an 802.11n  router - most of them will be now.  802.11n provides significantly greater distances as well as better speeds.

If you have a large house, and find the upstairs bedroom a problem you may want to look at extending the range by using a "Powerline" type device and second access point - Powerline devices transmit a signal through your electrical jacks - you will want to make sure that the upstairs house is on the same breaker as the downstairs entry point (Think of a Powerline device as a virtual ethernet cable).

"Download Time" is, of-course, highly subjective. If downloads are slow even when you are close to the router, you should look at replacing your Internet connection, or if they are slow from some devices but not your PC (again, when close to the router), you will need to upgrade your devices.